# Unit Test for virtual Keyboard

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit, keyboard-events, keyboard-hook

One of my projects I am developing is a Keyboard hook that traps some of the higher numbered function buttons (f13-f20). The tablet this will work on has buttons on it that are mapped to those higher function buttons. So any who I am making a class that has as its constructor input a Key (from System.Windows.Forms.Keys) and a AbstractTask. Since the use hook will perform various tasks I decided this would be a slick way of doing. One of the Tasks is a KeyboardTask. super simple class (I hope atleast)

```
public class KeyboardTask : AbstractTask
{
    private KeyboardTask ()
    { }
    public KeyboardTask (KeyboardCommand key)
    {
        Options = "{" + key + "}";
    }
    public override void PerformTask()
    {
        Globals.WriteLog("KeyboardTask:PerformTask()+");
        try
        {
            System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.Send(Options);
        }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {
            Globals.WriteExceptionLog(ex);
        }
        Globals.WriteLog("KeyboardTask:PerformTask()-");
    }
}
public enum KeyboardCommand
{
    BACKSPACE,//{BACKSPACE}, {BS}, or {BKSP}
    BREAK,//{BREAK}
    CAPSLOCK,//{CAPSLOCK}
    DELETE,//{DELETE} or {DEL}
    DOWN, //{DOWN}
    END,//{END}
    ENTER,//{ENTER}or ~
    ESC,//{ESC}
    //etc
}
```

So as a non-unit-test I compiled my program with this added to it

```
        ksel1 = new KeyboardSystemEventListener((Keys.F13), new KeyboardTask(KeyboardCommand.F1));//F1
        ksel6 = new KeyboardSystemEventListener((Keys.F18), new ECTask(EmbeddedControllerCommand.DecreaseBackLight));//RB
```

(there is a HUGE bug doing it this way, but that is already solved i just have to implement it) I put the program on my tablet, and I had IE open, pressed the F13 button and it opened IE's Help (YEAH!).. i pressed the F18 and the backlight decreased.. (no big suprise there)

so then I got to thinking.. there has to be a better way of doing (what I should have said is, why didn't I write my unit test first) So i started to write my unit test.. Problem is I don't have a F13 key.. ok not a huge deal i'll just change it to say my Home button on my keyboard, but then I tried to check for F1 and realized I have no clue how to do that with a Unit test. What i would prefer to see is something like this instead (take me out of the equation)

```
    [Test]
    public void TestKeyboardTask()
    {
        KeyboardTask kkt = new KeyboardTask(KeyboardCommand.F1);
        kkt.PerformTask();

        Assert.IsTrue(/*F1 key was pressed*/false);
    }
```

any ideas? I'm using NUnit 2.6.2 and Visual studio 2012 pro. I prefer to use NUnit as the VS test suite doesn't seem as refined (althoough would be a billion times more conveniant if it worked)

Comment: HA.. figured it out.. Super simple too. Basically I made a form with a text box in it. Added a keydown listener. On KeyDown I set a field called PressedKey to e.KeyData and then set dialog result to OK. I'll show code when i can.

Answer (score 1):

**Test Class**

```
    [Test]
    public void TestKeyboardTask()
    {
        KeyboardTask kkt = new KeyboardTask(KeyboardCommand.F1);
        using (MockKeyboardTest f = new MockKeyboardTest())
        {
            f.ShowDialog(kkt);
            Assert.AreEqual(Keys.F1, f.PressedKey);
        }
    }
```

**Mock keyboard Test**

```
class MockKeyboardTest : Form
{
    public MockKeyboardTest()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        PressedKey = Keys.BrowserBack;
    }
    public void ShowDialog(KeyboardTask kkt)
    {
        Keyboard = kkt;
        base.ShowDialog();

    }
    public void InitializeComponent()
    {
        this.Shown += MockKeyboardTest_Shown;
        KeyboardTestTextbox.AcceptsTab = true;
        KeyboardTestTextbox.Location = new Point(2, 22);
        KeyboardTestTextbox.MaxLength = 50;
        KeyboardTestTextbox.Multiline = true;
        KeyboardTestTextbox.Size = new Size(195, 25);
        KeyboardTestTextbox.KeyDown += this.KeyboardTestTextbox_KeyDown;

        Controls.Add(KeyboardTestTextbox);
    }

    void MockKeyboardTest_Shown(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        Keyboard.PerformTask();
    }

    private void KeyboardTestTextbox_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        PressedKey = e.KeyData;
        this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
    }
    private TextBox KeyboardTestTextbox = new TextBox();
    private KeyboardTask Keyboard;
    public Keys PressedKey;
}
```

works like a charm.